# How can I back out excess IRA contributions when my IRA has a zero balance?

Tags: roth-ira, ira, recharacterization, excess-contribution

I accidentally over contributed $25 to my traditional IRA last year giving a total non-deductible contribution of $5025. This was then converted along with all my traditional IRAs into Roth IRAs in 2010.

Can I make a 2011 contribution of $25 to my traditional IRA (so it no longer has a zero balance) and use that to fund the removal of excess $25 contribution from 2010?  Or must I instead back out the Roth conversion via a recharacterization in order to fund the removal of excess contribution?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd call the IRS to be sure.  but if you can unwind this before your taxes are due you won't owe the 6% tax on your excess contribution.

Here's [the IRS page](http://www.irs.gov/publications/p590/ch01.html#en_US_2010_publink1000230658) with this information.  (Under Excess Contribution Tax.)  I couldn't find a direct answer to your question.

If this is impractical then you can also (I believe) contribute $25 less than you're allowed to in 2011 to the appropriate IRA, and you're clean.  You will owe an extra $1.50 in taxes, though.

But [call the IRS](http://www.irs.gov/help/article/0,,id=96730,00.html).  They've been very helpful to me the times I've called.

Answer (score 3):

Two steps - paperwork to recharacterize the $25 to traditional, then withdraw that $25.